# Oracle Query : One to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

In my application there are one-to-many relationship as explained below.

Table one : Application

| app_id | app_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | XYZ |

Table two : Application_attribute [One application can have multiple attribute and variable list of attribute]

| App_attr_id | app_id | attr_name | attr_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | attr1 | white |
| 2 | 1 | attr2 | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | attr3 | 45 |
| 4 | 2 | attr1 | red |
| 5 | 2 | attr2 | 12 |
| 6 | 2 | attr4 | 45 |
| 7 | 2 | attr7 | 62 |

Each application can have variable list of attributes.

Query Requirement

I want to fetch list of application based on multiple attribute.

Example get list of application whose attributes are attr1=white,attr2=12,attr3=45

In above case, problem can be solved by joining application table with application_attribute table 3 times but attribute will vary per application so it will not be generic solution.

Query Solution for my requirement

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM application a,
       application_attribute at1,
       application_attribute at2,
       application_attribute at3
 WHERE a.app_id = at1.app_id
   AND a.app_id = at2.app_id
   AND a.app_id = at3.app_id
   AND at1.attr_name = 'attr1'
   AND at1.attr_value = 'white'
   AND at2.attr_name = 'attr2'
   AND at2.attr_value = '12'
   AND at3.attr_name = 'attr3'
   AND at3.attr_value = '45'
```

Expected Result

| app_id | app_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |

One option is two create dynamic query. Is it possible to write generic query which can be used to search n number of attribute like 3,4,5..n ?

Comment: What's this : `attr1=white,attr2=12,attr3=45`, a concatenated string ?

Comment: I have added query which will solve my problem but it will not be generic query. Please check

Comment: well, can you add the expected result too?

Comment: Added expected result

Answer (score 1):

You want to select applications where exist certain attributes. So, select from the application table and have a where clause checkink the existence of the attributes with `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
select * 
from aplication
where app_id in (select app_id from application_attribute where attr_name = 'attr1' and attr_value = 'white')
  and app_id in (select app_id from application_attribute where attr_name = 'attr2' and attr_value = '12')
  and app_id in (select app_id from application_attribute where attr_name = 'attr3' and attr_value = '45')
order by app_id;
```

As to generic: Simply build the query with a programming language and a loop over the desired attributes. In Oracle you can use PL/SQL for this.

Comment: Yes query can be created dynamically.

Comment: Then do that. You can even make this `where 1=1` and then add `and app_id in (...)` for every attribute. This can be done in PL/SQL, but just the same in Java, C#, you name it. After all it's just a simple loop.

Comment: I think dynamic query could be slower that the reason i am evaluating other option. I also mentioned in my question it can solved using dynamic query.

Comment: You are looking for an alternative? Like putting the requested key/values in one table and have a fix query that runs against these? That would require inserts into that parameter table before running the query, though. Or you could write a recursive query building those rows from a string like 'attr1=white,attr2=12,attr3=45'. I doubt that these solutions would be faster than building the query dynamically. Working with a variable number of conditions just has these drawbacks.

Comment: Hmmm, Thanks for all suggestions really appreciate all your help, As of now I solved it using dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` and a `HAVING` clause in the correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   application a
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   application_attribute aa
         WHERE  a.app_id = aa.app_id
         AND    (aa.attr_name, aa.attr_value)
                  IN (('attr1', 'white'), ('attr2', '12'), ('attr3', '45'))
         HAVING COUNT(/*DISTINCT*/ aa.attr_name) = 3 
       )
```

*Note: If there can be duplicate attribute values then you can `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` rather than just `COUNT(...)`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE application (app_id, app_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'XYZ' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Application_attribute (App_attr_id, app_id, attr_name, attr_value) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'attr1', 'white' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'attr2', '12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'attr3', '45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'attr1', 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2, 'attr2', '12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2, 'attr4', '45' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 2, 'attr7', '62' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | APP_ID | APP_NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ABC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=59882597d258f688d3447e52e778d74f)*

Answer (score 0):

If we re-write your query using joins there will be the 3 variables that you need to change in the WHERE. This will make it much easier to modify them.

```
Select a.* 
from application a
left join application-attribute at1 on a.app_id = at1.app_id and at1.attr_name = 'attr1'
left join application_attribute at2 on a.app_id = at2.app_id and at2.attr_name = 'attr2'
left join application_attribute at3 on a.app_id = at3.app_id and at3.attr_name = 'attr3'
left join application_attribute at4 on a.app_id = at4.app_id and at4.attr_name = 'attr4'
where  at1.attr_value = 'white' 
   and at2.attr_value = '12' 
   and at3.attr_value = '45'
/*   and at4.attr_value = not needed */
;
```

Comment: Thanks, Some application may have 4 attribute and in such cases may need to search based on 4 attributes. I want generic query which will cater to n attributes.

Comment: You can use `LEFT JOIN` so that it doesn't block if not found and comment out or remove the line in the **WHERE**, as shown

Comment: The expected outcome is generic query able to support n number of attribute and allow to query on n number of attributes

Comment: If you want more generic you need dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables only once by conditionally matching the values of `attr_name` and `attr_value` columns while filtering out the result only for the returning records with exactly triple attribute names such as

```sql
SELECT a.app_id, a.app_name
  FROM application a
  JOIN application_attribute aa
    ON aa.app_id = a.app_id
 WHERE DECODE( aa.attr_name, 'attr1', aa.attr_value ) = 'white' -- you can make these literals parametric by prefixing with : or & such as &p_attr1 and enter 'white' whenever prompted
    OR DECODE( aa.attr_name, 'attr2', aa.attr_value ) = '12'
    OR DECODE( aa.attr_name, 'attr3', aa.attr_value ) = '45'  
 GROUP BY a.app_id, a.app_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT aa.attr_name)=3
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=860b988449ed151195e522de34b8f0cd)</kbd>